# How can I add dynamic url in flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an e-commerce application and want users to be able to share products. I am using static routes.

```
static Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    var routingData = settings.name?.getRoutingData;
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('This is the route name ${settings.name}');
    switch (settings.name) {
      case PhoneAuth.routeName:
        return PhoneAuth.route();
      case ForgetPassword.routeName:
        return ForgetPassword.route();
      case Wrapper.routeName:
        return Wrapper.route();
      case Login.routeName:
        return Login.route();
      case SignUp.routeName:
        return SignUp.route();
      case HomeScreen.routeName:
        return HomeScreen.route();
      case CartScreen.routeName:
        return CartScreen.route();
      case LuckyDrawScreen.routeName:
        return LuckyDrawScreen.route();
      case ProfileScreen.routeName:
        return ProfileScreen.route();
      case WishListScreen.routeName:
        return WishListScreen.route();
      case WinnerScreen.routeName:
        return WinnerScreen.route();
      case DetailsScreen.routeName:
        return DetailsScreen.route(product: settings.arguments as Product);
      case BillingScreen.routeName:
        return BillingScreen.route();
      case CheckoutScreen.routeName:
        return CheckoutScreen.route();
      case CatalogScreen.routeName:
        return CatalogScreen.route(category: settings.arguments as Categories);
      case admin_Screen.routeName:
        return admin_Screen.route();

      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
```

But it only shows the route name and does not shows the product id. I have also tried passing product id using locator and navigator service but it doesn't even show page route name.

```
    Route<dynamic> generatedRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
      var routingData = settings.name?.getRoutingData;
    
      switch (settings.name) {
        case HomeRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const HomeScreen(), settings);
        case WrapperRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const Wrapper(), settings);
        case LoginRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const Login(), settings);
        case SignupRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const SignUp(), settings);
        case CartRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const CartScreen(), settings);
        case LuckyDrawRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const LuckyDrawScreen(), settings);
        case OTPRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const PhoneAuth(), settings);
        case BillRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const BillingScreen(), settings);
        case ProfileRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const ProfileScreen(), settings);
        case ProductRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(
              DetailsScreen(product: settings.arguments as Product), settings);
        case WishListRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const WishListScreen(), settings);
        case WinnerScreenRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const WinnerScreen(), settings);
        case CheckoutRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const CheckoutScreen(), settings);
        case CatalogRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(
              CatalogScreen(category: settings.arguments as Categories), settings);
        case AdminRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const admin_Screen(), settings);
        case ForgotRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(ForgetPassword(), settings);
        case ErrorsRoute:
          return _getPageRoute(const Error(), settings);
        default:
          return _getPageRoute(const Error(), settings);
      }
    }
    
    PageRoute _getPageRoute(Widget child, RouteSettings settings) {
      return _FadeRoute(child: child, routeName: settings.name);
    }
    
    class _FadeRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
      final Widget child;
      final String? routeName;
      _FadeRoute({required this.child, required this.routeName})
          : super(
              settings: RouteSettings(name: routeName),
              pageBuilder: (
                BuildContext context,
                Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
              ) =>
                  child,
              transitionsBuilder: (
                BuildContext context,
                Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
                Widget child,
              ) =>
                  FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: child,
              ),
            );
    }
```

I am new to flutter navigation and don't know a lot about it. I have created this code using  youtube tutorial which the youtuber didn't complete.

Comment: you should use `go_router` package it works perfectly for me in same scenario

Comment: you are looking for `navigator 2`, you can check my [project](https://github.com/yeasin50/lisa_fischer) and [practice](https://github.com/yeasin50/Dart_-Flutter_Advanced/blob/master/navigator2/demo1.dart)